# Create a Jar from String?

Tags: string, executable-jar

I've seen some interesting questions and answers on programmatically creating Jar files from within other Jar files. "Machines making machines," if you will.

This stirred a question in my novice mind: can you create an executable Jar file from a String without first outputting it to a source file or temp file? I've Googled the question and haven't found an answer, mostly because I'm not sure where to look.

At any rate, an illustration may help explain my question. Say I have something like this:

```
String newClass = "class testing{ \n"+
                  "    public static void main(String args[]){ \n"+
                  "        System.out.println(\"This works!\"); \n"+
                  "    } \n"+
                  "}";
```

Can I compile that into an executable Jar file without first outputting it to a .java file or a temporary file? And then, when I double-click it the outputted Jar, would I get a console window that says "This works!"? (Granted there is no pause in the above code, so I wouldn't actually see it.)

Basically, my curiosity stems from my wondering if people can theoretically create programs without the source code ever having touched their hard drive. I know people can decompile programs and what-not; but still, it seems a legitimate question. Decryption programs, for example, that might store a key the user inputs; or a user who buys a program online that registers itself to them on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you will need an external library for that.  See [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/).

However, I don't think that it makes a big difference for decryption programs and such.  The decryption key has had to make its way into the program; its creator program presumably was on disk, or maybe the creator's creator was.  If the key is nowhere on the disk or in the user's head, it must have been generated on the fly and you will lose the decrypted data once the power is off.  This may be OK; but you might as well generate the key on the fly in the memory of a traditionally executed program.

There are also memory management techniques (swapping, hibernation) that blur the difference between memory and RAM on some systems, as far as security goes.